# Invalid URL formed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, url

I am getting the following URL in my code (as a string) --

`$image_url =""http:\\/\\/hello.us\\/kruger\\/web\\/invest\\/api\\/graph\\/gfx\\/tags\\/shop.png\""`

However when i use this (in a facebook app) -- it says..
[$image_url] should represent a valid URL

What string operation (or something else) should i do to make the URL A valid image url? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is error in the string `""` at the start

```
""http:\\/\\/hello.us\\/kruger\\/web\\/invest\\/api\\/graph\\/gfx\\/tags\\/shop.png\""
```

I suppose the string is `"\"http:\\/\\/hello.us\\/kruger\\/web\\/invest\\/api\\/graph\\/gfx\\/tags\\/shop.png\""`

`\\` in the string evaluates to `\`

Facebook api sees the url as this `""http:\/\/hello.us\/kruger\/web\/invest\/api\/graph\/gfx\/tags\/shop.png""` so it is unable to understand the url.

Replace the extra `\` and `"` using the following code

`url = data.replace(/([\\"])/g,'');`

`url` returned is `http://hello.us/kruger/web/invest/api/graph/tags/shop.png`

```js
var data ="\"http:\\/\\/hello.us\\/kruger\\/web\\/invest\\/api\\/graph\\/gfx\\/tags\\/shop.png\""; // YOUR CURRENT DATA

url=data.replace(/([\\"])/g,'');

console.log(url);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```